# How do I specify a Bouncy Castle public key from a Byte array?

Tags: c#, encryption, public-key-encryption

I need to implement key exchange through an I2C interface with a microcontoller, with the keys transferred byte by byte. I am working in Visual Studio 2022, C#.  Because I need access to the Secret Agreement (ECDH), I can't use the Visual Studio encryption library, so have turned to Bouncy Castle.  I am able to get the two parts of the public key into Byte arrays to send to the micro - example code shown - but have not been able to figure out how to put the public key received from the micro into a Bouncy Castle public key object to use in generating a secret agreement.

```
        public void TestBC()
        {
            String SecretString = "";
            int j;

            AsymmetricKeyPair<AsymmetricECPublicKey, AsymmetricECPrivateKey> InitiatorKey = GenerateECDHKeyPair();
            AsymmetricKeyPair<AsymmetricECPublicKey, AsymmetricECPrivateKey> RecipientKey = GenerateECDHKeyPair();
            String RecipPublicKeyX = RecipientKey.PublicKey.W.XCoord.ToString();
            String RecipPublicKeyY = RecipientKey.PublicKey.W.YCoord.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(RecipPublicKeyW + "\r\n" + RecipPublicKeyX + "\r\n" + RecipPublicKeyY);
            Byte[] SecretAgreement = GetSecretAgreement(InitiatorKey.PrivateKey, RecipientKey.PublicKey);
            Byte[] publicX = ConvertHexStringToByteArray(RecipPublicKeyX);
            Byte[] publicY = ConvertHexStringToByteArray(RecipPublicKeyY);

            for(j=0; j<SecretAgreement.Length; j++)
                SecretString += String.Format("{0:X2}",SecretAgreement[j]);
            MessageBox.Show(SecretString);
        }

        public AsymmetricKeyPair<AsymmetricECPublicKey, AsymmetricECPrivateKey> GenerateECDHKeyPair()
        {
            FipsEC.KeyGenerationParameters KeyGenParameters = new FipsEC.KeyGenerationParameters(FipsEC.DomainParams.P256).For(FipsEC.Cdh);
            FipsEC.KeyPairGenerator KpGen = CryptoServicesRegistrar.CreateGenerator(KeyGenParameters, new Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SecureRandom());
            return KpGen.GenerateKeyPair();
        }

        public static byte[] GetSecretAgreement(AsymmetricECPrivateKey InitiatorPrivate, AsymmetricECPublicKey RecipientPublic)
        {
            IAgreementCalculatorService agreeFact = CryptoServicesRegistrar.CreateService(InitiatorPrivate);
            IAgreementCalculator<FipsEC.AgreementParameters> agreement = agreeFact.CreateAgreementCalculator(FipsEC.Cdh);
            return agreement.Calculate(RecipientPublic);
        }

        public static byte[] ConvertHexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
        {
            if (hexString.Length % 2 != 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "The hex string cannot have an odd number of digits: {0}", hexString));
            }

            byte[] data = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
            for (int index = 0; index < data.Length; index++)
            {
                string byteValue = hexString.Substring(index * 2, 2);
                data[index] = byte.Parse(byteValue, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }

            return data;
        }
```

Visual Studio intellisense does not show any constructors, properties, or methods for the AsymmetricECPublicKey object that will allow me to put in the pbulic key from a Byte array (or string).  And the agreement calculator appears to require a public key object.  I found a couple of similar questions already posted, but they did not help me.  Does anyone know how to use a Byte array or string to do this?

Comment: EC public keys are often compressed and serialized using the format specified in SEC-1. This code (albeit in Java) how to convert byte arrays to/from public key using BC. https://github.com/aws/aws-encryption-sdk-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/encryptionsdk/internal/TrailingSignatureAlgorithm.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preliminary note: The question and answer refer to the [C#/BouncyCastle FIPS version](https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips-csharp/) and not the regular C#/BouncyCastle version.

If the public key is given as raw x and y coordinates, it should first be converted to the uncompressed format. The uncompressed format is given by the concatenation of a leading 0x04 byte, the x coordinate and the y coordinate. The last two are 32 bytes each for P-256 (if the x coordinate is smaller, it must be padded from the front with 0x00 to 32 bytes; the same applies to the y coordinate):

```cs
Byte[] publicX = ...;
Byte[] publicY = ...;
Byte[] uncompressedKey = new byte[1 + 32 + 32];  // pad too short values (i.e. values < 32 bytes) with leading 0x00
uncompressedKey[0] = 0x04;
Buffer.BlockCopy(publicX, 0, uncompressedKey, 1 + (32 - publicX.Length), publicX.Length);          
Buffer.BlockCopy(publicY, 0, uncompressedKey, 1 + 32 + (32 - publicY.Length), publicY.Length);
```

The uncompressed key can then be imported as follows:

```cs
FipsEC.KeyGenerationParameters keyGenParameters = new FipsEC.KeyGenerationParameters(FipsEC.DomainParams.P256).For(FipsEC.Cdh);
AsymmetricECPublicKey publicKey = new AsymmetricECPublicKey(FipsEC.Alg, KeyGenParameters.DomainParameters, KeyGenParameters.DomainParameters.Curve.DecodePoint(uncompressedKey));
```

For completeness: It is also possible to convert the key to the compressed format and import it. The compressed format is the concatenation of a leading 0x02 byte (if y is even) or 0x03 byte (if y is odd) and the x coordinate (with this information the public key is uniquely determined, since from this information the y coordinate can be reconstructed).

Comment: Topaco - thanks for the detailed explanation and example code.  Also, I did not realize that only the x coordinate and y is even/odd byte is needed to transmit the PublicKey - this will speed up the exchange.  It appears that DecodePoint accepts both compressed and uncompressed forms.

Comment: @russ - Right, `DecodePoint()` can handle uncompressed and compressed keys.

Comment: Follow-on question: in TestBC of my example code, the .ToString method gave me 32 bytes each (64 characters in the string) for the x and y coordinates (I only ran this once or twice).  Today, I had several tests that only gave me 63 characters in the string for the y coordinate.  On the fourth or fifth attempt, I got 64 characters.  Do you know if the .ToString method is simply not returning a leading 0 if the first byte is less than 0x10?

Comment: I just noticed that the Bouncy Castle API allows me to see the source code, and it appears that the ToString method does not prepend a 0 character, if needed, when converting the first 32-byte integer, of the BigInteger, to a string.

Comment: @russ - Correct. According to the source code, `ECFieldElement#ToString()` internally executes `BigInteger#ToString(16)` and the latter does not pad with a leading 0, i.e. `Console.WriteLine(new BigInteger("03a5ff", 16).ToString(16))` returns `3a5ff`. An alternative is e.g. `ECFieldElement#GetEncoded()`, which returns an (unsigned) `byte[]` that can be hex encoded with e.g. `Convert.ToHexString()` (which also pads).

Comment: Topaco - Thanks again, GetEncoded() may be a more appropriate option for what I'm doing.